# Spring boot rollback multi datasource

Tags: spring-boot, transactional

My service do a delete in 2 database, oracle and postgresql. When one of repository throw a exception, the other one dont rollback.

Example:

```
public MyService { 
@Autowired private OracleRep oracleRep;
@Autowired private PostgreRep postgreRep ;

@Transactional
public void delete(Long id){

    oracleRep.delete(id);
    postgreRep.delete(id);
}
}

public OracleRepImpl { 

@Autowired private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate ;

public void delete(Long id){
    //do delete
}
}

public PostgreRepImpl { 

@Autowired private @Qualifier("postgresql")NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate ;

public void delete(Long id){
    //do delete
}
}
```

I guess the annotation @Transactional dont share the transcational between database.

How could i implement this behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transaction management for multiple database Using Spring & Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802871/transaction-management-for-multiple-database-using-spring-hibernate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the database configuratio i built this:

```
@Bean(name = "postgresqlTransaction")

 public DataSourceTransactionManager  postgresqlDataSourceTransactionManager(@Qualifier("postgresqlDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
```

}

Then i build a annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional("postgresqlTransaction")
public @interface TransactionalPostgresql {
}
```

and now:

```
@TransactionalPostgresql 
@Transactional
public void delete(Long id){

    oracleRep.delete(id);
    postgreRep.delete(id);
}
```