# @Transactional with multiple Transaction Manager and multiple databases

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

> I have the below set up for a SpringBoot application:

1. **Database1 - TransactionManagerDatabase1**
2. **Database2 - TransactionManagerDatabase2**

   ```
   Transactional(value = "TransactionManagerDatabase1", readOnly = true)
    public void getResults() {
      // select a row from table in Database1
      // select a row from table in Database2

    DataSource dataSourceDB2 = SpringContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("TransactionManagerDatabase2", DataSource.class);       
    dataSourceDB2.getPool().getActive(); //This is returning an active connection with Database2

   }
   ```

When the `@Transactional` is applied for **Database1**, How can **Database2** still hold an active connection ??

Answer (score 1):

According to this: [Transaction management for multiple database Using Spring & Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802871/transaction-management-for-multiple-database-using-spring-hibernate)

You can specify multiple TMs like so:

```
<bean>
  <bean id="transactionManager1"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory1" />
    <qualifier value="account"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager2"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
    <qualifier value="businessData"/>
</bean>
```

Then you can do this to specify which TM you're needing:

```
public class TransactionalService {

  @Transactional("account")
  public void setSomethingInAccount() { ... }

  @Transactional("businessData")
  public void doSomethingInBusinessData() { ... }
}
```

> ```
> public class TransactionalService {
>
>       @Transactional("businessData")
>       public void doSomethingInBusinessData(
>       @Transactional
>       ("account") -> {...}) 
>       {...}
>     }
> ```

Comment: I have a requirement to call both of the databases in a single method & use transaction on one of them.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a lambda expression. That would achieve the same endgame but only use one method. That code isn't tested but the general idea may help you. Alternatively, you could make both methods static and make a third method that calls both of them.