# How to handle 2 databases in one method?

Tags: java, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a Spring Boot RESTful CRUD service in car rental domain.

From the high overview, it's a simple CRUD app with SQL database and all such entities as a Car, Client, Lease, etc.

Now I have to introduce a report generation feature that aimed to process lease data and calculate some statistics based on data in SQL db and persist the report into MongoDB.

I've already implemented it by creating a `ReportGenerationService` that depends on `OriginDataService` and `MongoService`.
`ReportGenerationService` generates the report based on a data returned by `OriginDataService`. In turn, `OriginDataService` has a method `getData()` that do a number of calls to DAO layer and thus annotated with `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)`. I want the returned data to be consistent. After getting the data `ReportGenerationService` generates a report and persists it by invoking `MongoService`'s `persist(Report)` method.

In my implementation I `get data -> generate report -> persist report`.

But what if the base data and report can't fit into RAM?
The solution is to select it little by little, generate a part of the report, persist the part of the report and after all rows of data is processed merge the report.

It means that one method should read the data, processes it and persists.
I also want my method to read data with Repeatable Read isolation level, then I have to annotate the method with `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)`. But since 2 dbs are used in the method the `@Transactional` will spread on both of them, and I want only SQL to use it.

How can I do gradually reads and writes to different dbs?

Answer (score 0):

**Refer below links and code sample, it may help you to resolve your issue.**

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html?page=2

[Transaction management for multiple database Using Spring & Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802871/transaction-management-for-multiple-database-using-spring-hibernate)

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="com.springsource.open.db.ChainedTransactionManager">
  <property name="transactionManagers">
    <list>
      <bean
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      </bean>
      <bean
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="otherDataSource" />
      </bean>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```